# MGTwitter Sessions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I am using the MGTwitterEngine+Oauth library to integrate Twitter into my iPhone app. Using the below included code I am able to allow users to log into twitter.

```
if(_engine) return;


    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey = @"XXXXXX";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"XXXXXXXXX";


    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

    if (controller)
    {
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    }
```

I also have the following delegate methods for handling the callback.

```
#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate

- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];



    [defaults setObject: data forKey: @"authData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username {

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];
}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterController Delegate

- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);

    //tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self updateStream:nil];
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerFailed: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Failure");
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Canceled");
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

the users are able to tweet using the following code:

```
[_engine sendUpdate:@"Tweet"];
```

This all seems pretty standard but for some reason if I try to create another engine from another class or for a returning user, the user is forced to relogin in order to create a usable engine.  What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure if you made a mistake in writing the problem above but if you made another instance of the class then its like running a fresh program and no data is stored, so if you are trying to include the file to use the sessions etc then you dont need to create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is right. You have created the new instance so it is asking for the authentication.